# Picture height responsive Bootstrap 2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a responsive design for my movie portal using Bootstrap 2.

I want to make the image height on a level with the other pictures. When i manually set picture height then it looks beautiful and all pictures are on the level with the other pictures.

But when I open website on tablet, then all the pictures look compressed!

Example 1:

[image]

If I remove height from pictures, then pictures are not on the same level with the other and looks bad.

Example 2:

[image]

Maybe you have idea how to fix it?

HTML:

```
<div class="span2 item all">
   <div class="picframe img-polaroid">
      <span class="overlay">
      <span class="info-area">
      <a class="img-icon-url" href="/movie"></a>
      </span>
      <span class="pf_text">
      <span class="project-name">Movie Name</span>
      <span>Genre</span>
      </span>
      </span>    
      <img data-original="pictur.jpg" src="picture.jpg" alt="" class="poster"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.poster {
   width:170px;
   height:226px;
}
```

Comment: share your HTML and CSS code

Comment: You need to set the height only without the width if you want to keep the aspect ratio intact.

Comment: I tried, but the same! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use Bootstrap 3 because it's very easy to make responsive image:

[Responsive images](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-responsive-images)

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```